# Fragments overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I have an action bar with 3 tabs, each tab opens a fragment. The third tab, "Catalog", has a list:
[image]

When I click on an item it opens another fragment, which is not part of the action bar:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.category1:    
        Fragment cosmeticsFragment = new ActivityCosmetics();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, cosmeticsFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.setTransition(1);

        transaction.commit();
        break;
        ...
```

This is what it looks like after that:
[image]

From this point, if I go to other tab and then return to the Catalog tab, I see the 2 previous fragments overlapping each other:

[image]

How do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 5):

You can manage your fragments by searching them by tag. When adding fragment to backstack add TAG name

```
transaction.addToBackStack("myCustomFragmentTag");
```

If you want to destroy Fragment anywhere in application :

```
Fragment previousInstance = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myCustomFragmentTag");
                if (previousInstance != null)
                    transaction.remove(previousInstance);
```

You can try override some behavior so this line of code 'll destroy initialized last Fragment

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: I tried to use it as follows: `transaction.addToBackStack("CategoryFragment");` and then tried to use the rest of the code in onResume and onTabReselected methods. But I still saw these fragments overlapping...

Answer (score 5):

Setting a background to fragment layout would fix this.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: android:background="?android:colorBackground"

Comment: also you have to add below so clicks wont get passed to the old fragment ==>  android:clickable="true"

Comment: adding a background to the fragment will not be the correct solution. Its is just an hack

Answer (score 1):

According to this question  :
[Android: fragments overlapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274732/android-fragments-overlapping-issue?answertab=active#tab-top)

all you need is to just set a background color to your  in XML file

Solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for tabs..

> ```
>    public class Tabs extends TabActivity {
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);
>     Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
>     TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
>     TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
>    // Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
>     // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
>     Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Social.class);
>     // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
>     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("app_name").setIndicator("Practice",
>                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_social))
>                   .setContent(intent1);
>     tabHost.addTab(spec);
>     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbgg);
>     // Do the same for the other tabs
>     Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, Web.class);
>     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("application").setIndicator("Application",
>                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_web))
>                   .setContent(intent2);
>     tabHost.addTab(spec);
>     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbgg);
>     Intent intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, Catalog.class);
>     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("toplinks").setIndicator("Top Links",
>                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_catalog))
>                   .setContent(intent3);
>     tabHost.addTab(spec);
>     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbgg);
>     tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
> }
> }
> ```

In your layout xml

> ```
>     <TabHost 
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
> android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
> android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
>   <LinearLayout 
> android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
> android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical">
>   <TabWidget 
> android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
> android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
>  <FrameLayout 
> android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
> android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
>  </LinearLayout>
>  </TabHost>
> ```