# Android: Passing Objects Between Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Before i start, i have look through question such as:

[Passing data between fragments: screen overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253666/passing-data-between-fragments-screen-overlap)
[How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

as well as Android docs:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

as well as this article:

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

Though all the cases mentioned above similar to what i have, it is not entirely identical. I followed a good tutorial here (Some portion of my code is based on this article):

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

I have the following files:

**RegisterActivity.java

NonSwipeableViewPager.java

ScreenSliderAdapter.java

RegisterOneFragment.java

RegisterTwoFragment.java**

And the following layouts:

**activity_register.xml

fragment_register_one.xml

fragment_register_two.xml**

What i am trying to achieve is passing an Serializable object from RegisterFragmentOne to RegisterFragmentTwo.

So far this is what i have done (some codes are omitted):

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity
             implements RegisterOneFragment.OnEmailRegisteredListener{

    public static NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;
    private ScreenSliderAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Initilization
        mAdapter = new ScreenSliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void onEmailRegistered(int position, Registration regData){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("regData", regData);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
    }
}
```

**ScreenSliderAdapter.java**

```
public class ScreenSliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public ScreenSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new RegisterOneFragment();
        case 1:
            return new RegisterTwoFragment();
        case 2:
            return new RegisterThreeFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**NonSwipeableViewPager.java** (extending ViewPager class, and overrides the following)

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
```

**RegisterOneFragment.java**

```
public class RegisterOneFragment extends Fragment {
    OnEmailRegisteredListener mCallBack;
    public interface OnEmailRegisteredListener {
        /** Called by RegisterOneFragment when an email is registered */
        public void onEmailRegistered(int position, Registration regData);
    }

public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallBack = (OnEmailRegisteredListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnEmailRegisteredListener");
    }
}

... And some to execute some HTTP request via separate thread...
}
```

What i am trying to accomplish is that when ever a user pressed a button on RegisterOneFragment, a data will be sent to a server (and returns some validation over JSON). If the returned data is valid, the the application should go to the next fragment which is RegistrationTwoFragment.

I am having some confusion as how to pass objects between fragments, since my Fragments is created using an Adapter. And that Adapter is then attached to my Activity.

Can anyone help me with this? Thx

**Edit 1:**

I tried to make a shortcut (unfortunately does not work) like so:

In RegisterActivity i created:

```
public Registration regData;
```

and in RegisterOneFragment:

```
/* PLACED ON POST EXECUTE */
((RegisterActivity)getActivity()).regData = regData;
```

Finally called it in RegisterTwoFragment

```
Registration regData;
regData = ((RegisterActivity) getActivity()).regData;
```

It throws a nullPointerExceptions

**Edit 2**

Just to be clear, RegisterActivty contains multiple fragments. And the only way user can navigate between fragment is by clicking a button. The Activity has no Tab bar.

Comment: can you tell about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126867/how-to-access-custom-arraylist-in-fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally have setters or methods similar to this in the containing activity.

So if I understand correctly, you want the user to access `RegistrationOneFragment`, then when completed, use this data, validate it, and if valid, pass it along to `RegistrationTwoFragment` and move the user to this `Fragment`.

Could you simply call `validateJson(regData)` in your `onEmailRegistered` method to handle the validation in your activity, if it succeeds, commit a transaction to `RegistrationTwoFragment`.

Then all you need are getters and setters in your activity or Fragment to say `getRegistrationOneData()` in the activity or `setData(Registration args)` in the fragment as your examples show above.

I don't know of any way to pass the args directly into the Fragment.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am trying to do with my code. Referring to your solution, does that mean i don't have to use adapters? In the mean time i'll try to follow ur advice. Thx...

Comment: If you want to keep the pager and adapter then you should keep it, but I think you could also handle it easily with supportFragmentManager() and transactions.

Comment: I suppose you are right, it just that i am trying to get this done with as little efforts as possible...

Answer (score 8):

It's easy to share objects via implementing Serializable to your custom Object. I wrote a tutorial about this [here](http://virtualcompiler.blogspot.com/2014/06/share-object-between-fragments.html).

From Fragment One:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = 
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
OfficeCategoryFragment frag = new OfficeCategoryFragment();

Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
Division aDivision = divisionList.get(position);

// ensure your object has not null
if (aDivision != null) {
    bundles.putSerializable("aDivision", aDivision);
    Log.e("aDivision", "is valid");
} else {
    Log.e("aDivision", "is null");
}
frag.setArguments(bundles);
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

In Fragment two:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
Division division= (Division) bundle.getSerializable("aDivision");
Log.e("division TEST", "" + division.getName());
```

Comment: For someone trying to do something similar with less effort: use google gson to serialize your pojo to json and send it with the bundle. Its better because you dont need to implement serializable for every object, and when you change your objects properties (on your backend) you dont need to change the serializable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my question, which i am sure not the correct way to do that...

So in RegisterActivity.java i add + modified the following lines (thx to @sturrockad):

```
public Registration getRegistrationData(){
    return this.regData;
}

public void onEmailRegistered(int position, Registration regData){
    this.regData = regData;
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
}
```

Then in RegisterTwoFragments.java (or in the Fragment to which i want to receive the Object):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_two, container, false);
    regData = ((RegisterActivity) getActivity()).getRegistrationData();
    ...
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if you're happy with the get() methods solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used to set object with Pacelable or Serializable to transfer, but whenever I add other variables to object(model), I have to register it all. It's so inconvenient.

It's super easy to transfer object between activities or fragments.

[Android DataCache](http://github.com/kimkevin/AndroidDataCache)

1. put your data object to KimchiDataCache instance in your activity or fragment.

   ```
   User userItem = new User(1, "KimKevin");  // Sample Model

   KimchiDataCache.getInstance().put(userItem);

   // add your activity or fragment
   ```
2. Get your data object in your activity of fragment that you added.

   ```
   public class MainFragment extends Fragment{
        private User userItem;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            userItem = KimchiDataCache.getInstance().get(User.class);
        }
   ```

Comment: This has the behavoir of singleton pattern, which is very an antipattern, its pain with unit test.

Comment: For someone trying to do something similar with less effort: use google gson to serialize your pojo to json and send it with the bundle (setArguments).