# how to pass object from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Code of fragment MoneyTransferFragment......

```
MoneyTransferFragment moneyTransferFragment = new MoneyTransferFragment();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("UserValidateObject",userValidate);
                    b.putSerializable("BeneficiaryObject",beneficiaryDetails);
                    moneyTransferFragment.setArguments(b);
```

Code of second fragment where i want to retrive that object.......

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
    userValidate =(UserValidate) b.getSerializable("UserValidateObject");
    Log.i("getuserValidate",userValidate.toString());
```

showing error at Log that ..........

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code that actually loads your  `MoneyTransferFragment`

Comment: @suraj have you tried to make `UserValidate` class as a `Serilizable` or `Parcelable` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998239/android-passing-objects-between-fragments

Comment: Show the UserValidate class

Comment: @HsRaja Title is the same, question is much different

Comment: UserValidate it must implement Serilizable or Parceble

Comment: yes @user1140237.....I have implemented UserValidate class as Serializable

Comment: but just implemented....is there any changes need to do?

Comment: What is the second fragment ? Is it MoneyTransferFragment? If not it will crash like this.

Comment: but second fragment is in another activity not same activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your code
**From:**

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
userValidate =(UserValidate) b.getSerializable("UserValidateObject");
Log.i("getuserValidate",userValidate.toString());
```

**To:**

```
userValidate=(UserValidate)getArguments().getSerializable("UserValidateObject");
Log.i("getuserValidate",userValidate.toString());
```

Activity works:

```
    (YourObject)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("keyname");
```

Fragment Works:

```
 (YourObject)getArguments().getSerializable("keyname");
```

Comment: public class UserValidate implements Serializable{  //your methods and variables }

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: but second fragment is in another activity not same activity

Comment: can u explain how you are actually doing this all. Means from which activity or fragment to next activity/fragment

Comment: Activity A contains frgmaentA and Activity B contains fragmentB I want to pass object from frgmaentA  to fragmentB

Comment: ohh you are confusing  now. If activityB contains fragmentB then why are you calling fragementB from fragmentA. You need to call ActivityB first and then get these values at ActivityB and pass on to FragmentB

Comment: look above how to get serializable data in both

Comment: yes sir already I am calling ActivityB from fragmentA......but ActivityB contains fragmentB so I want to pass object from fragmentA to fragmentB

Comment: kkkkk.....means it is neccessary to get object at ActivityB and then pass it to fragmentB

Comment: thats why your fragments returning you a null value

Comment: done...thank u sir.....now how to pass object from ActivityB to fragmentB