# Fragments overlapping with DrawerLayout/NavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-design-library, fragmentmanager

Using a `DrawerLayout` with a `NavigationView` and a `FrameLayout` I want to switch `Fragment`s. That works great.
However, if I switch too quickly, then the `Fragment`s overlaps...

**It is like `executePendingTransactions()` does not work.**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="@240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationdrawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**If I switch `Fragment`s (too) rapidly (manually or by code with a 750ms delay on my Nexus 5), I get both `Fragment`s to overlap, with the second `Fragment` having the touch enabled BUT the first `Fragment` being on top...**

The first `Fragment` contains an `ImageView` and `TextView`s. The second `Fragment` contains a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` (if that could have anything to day with my issue). Yes I'm using AppCompat 22.2.0 and Design 22.2.0 libraries.

If I set a background color to both, then I can only see the first `Fragment`, and it never changes.

I tried `popBackStackImmediate()`, `executePendingTransactions()`, `remove(fragment)`, `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, [Android: fragments overlapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274732), delaying, and other things, without success.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
            navigationDrawer(menuItem.getItemId());
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        final MenuItem menuItem = mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
        if (menuItem != null) {
            navigationDrawer(menuItem.getItemId());
        }
    }
}

private void navigationDrawer(final int itemId) {
    final Fragment fragment = getFragment(itemId);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTrasaction()
        .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(itemId).setChecked(true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mNavigationView);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_first:
        case R.id.menu_second:
        case R.id.menu_third:
            navigationDrawer(item.getItemId());
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**EDIT**

In my `onCreate()` I was doing this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
    if (menuItem != null) {
        navigationDrawer(menuItem.getItemId());
    }
}
```

Which turns out to make a call too rapidly. Removing this code solved my issue (temporally, see below).

I still don't know why `executePendingTransactions()` did not prevent such weird issue...

**EDIT 2**

I thought about keeping a `boolean` (init to false) to keep track of when a `Fragment` transaction takes place. I set it to `true` in my `navigationDrawer()` and to `false` in `Fragment.onResume()`. Still no go...

So: still having problem on my `MainFragment` that loads an image using `Picasso` and switching too rapidly (800ms) to another `Fragment`: they still overlap...

Comment: can i see your some more code ..so that i can help you ..

Comment: @Moinkhan What part of it? I believe I posted the relative part. It's a basic DrawerLayout/NavigationView implementation.

Comment: the code you have provided was perfect. that's why i thought the problem can be in code, which is not provided over here ....

Comment: @Moinkhan added some code

Comment: Seems the click it's running BEFORE the onCreate, have you debugged?

Comment: How could it be? I can, with my own fingers, provoke this bug. So the UI is built and it went through `onCreate`().

Comment: I think your problem is due to your navigationDrawer() method getting called from the onCreate() method(when savedInstance is null) and also the listener for the NavigationView. At some point you may add more fragments than you want(which is why removing the code from onCreate seems to work ). Also the navigationDrawer() method should do some checks and not blindly add fragments no matter what, for example checking the fragment container for already present fragments(for the initial onCreate call), not adding fragments when the user selects the same menu option...

Comment: I did what I think was that, and answered my own question. Yet I managed to reproduce the bug, hence the bounty. To be sure, could you propose an answer with what you wrote and I'll try it the way you see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `onCreate()` I was doing this:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        final MenuItem menuItem = mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
        if (menuItem != null) {
            navigationDrawer(menuItem.getItemId());
        }
    }
```

Which turns out to make a call too rapidly. **Removing this code solved my issue.**

I still don't know:

> why `executePendingTransactions()` did not prevent such weird issue...

**EDIT**

Still having problem on my `MainFragment` that loads an image using `Picasso` and switching too rapidly (800ms) to another one: they still overlap...

**EDIT 2**

So I now use a boolean to mark if my `Activity` is transitioning a `Fragment` or not, with a minimal timer of 1s second between switches.

In my `Fragment`s `onViewCreated()`:

```
if (view != null) {
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Activity might be null
            getActivity().setTransitioning(false);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my `navigationDrawer()`:

```
if (isTransitioning()) {
    // Switching Fragments too fast
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Alternative way would be to check if the `Activity` passed `onResume()` at top of my `navigationDrawer()` method. Works even with faulty code now.

Comment: And that did not work: I set a `boolean` for as to when a transaction was in place, and made my `Fragment`s set that to false in `onResume()`. Still not working...

Answer (score 1):

You may try this ...
It will delay your frequent click ...

```
private final Handler mDrawerActionHandler = new Handler();
private static final long DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS = 250;

mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // your navigation code goes here
      }
}, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
```

Comment: Thought of that and did it already: did not work (plus that does not explain my issue). Thanks for the input anyway