# fragment overlap activity_main and activity_main is not removed

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

So what I want to do is something like this

- Select a item from NavigationView
- remove activity_main's content
- load and show the fragment I've selected

For example:

- I selected "Homepage" in NavigationView which should load Homepage.class
- Load the fragment_homepage.xml
- remove everything in activity_main.xml

What I am getting trouble is, no matter what I've selected in NavigationView, it shows up BOTH fragment_(whatIhaveSelected).xml and activity.xml which I don't want to.

Code:

MainActivity class

```
package to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                int id = item.getItemId();

                Fragment myFragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = null;

                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.homepage:
                        fragmentClass = Homepage.class;
                        break;
                    case R.id.station:
                        fragmentClass = Station.class;
                        break;
                    default:
                        fragmentClass = Homepage.class;
                        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.homepage);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "default Homepage clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    myFragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.flcontent, myFragment).commit();

                item.setCheckable(true);
                setTitle(item.getTitle());
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                // TODO
                // If first open app, it will show "app_name", but when clicked on "Homepage", it will show "主頁", waiting to fix
                toolbar.setTitle(item.getTitle());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (this.drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="activity_main's textView" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Homepage class

```
package to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Homepage.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Homepage#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Homepage extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Homepage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Homepage.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Homepage newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Homepage fragment = new Homepage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

fragment_homepage.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="to.epac.factorycraft.drawerlayouttest.Homepage"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Homepage Fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you need to do is a FragmentTransaction. check this tutorial out. 
https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it, ft.replace(R.id.flcontent, myFragment).commit(); not doing what you mean? Also, do I have to work on addToBackStack()?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is to somehow replace the content of an activity with a fragment. well if that is the case you simply shouldn't do it. instead try to make a fragment for the content of your activity, for example instead of MainActivity create a MainFragment and put the content of the activity inside the fragment. then for every item on the drawer layout create a new fragment.

so create a place holder activity with a <fragment> tag inside it. with fragment transaction load the MainFragment inside this tag with ft.replace(R.id.flcontent, myFragment).commit()

Comment: So what you mean is I can delete activity_main.xml and make something called fragment_main.xml and let MainActivity load fragment_main.xml instead of activity_main.xml, also copy everything from activity_main.xml to fragment_main.xml? But I don't what do you mean about <fragment> tag
Or I have to create a new thing called MainFragment? And what can I do to load these thing?

Comment: well I ran your code. the answer is pretty easy. just set a background color for your fragment, android:background="#F5F5F5" in your fragment_homepage.xml root tag. in your case LinearLayout.

Comment: I have done some research before and I got something similar to what you say(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18274767/9010038), but in the same post, most of them said that it is just a trick, adding a background color in order to hide the previous fragment seems not to be the best solution

Comment: you are not hiding the previous fragment, in your case there is not a previous fragment ! you are hiding the activity content. if you do another ft.replace with another fragment for the second time, then the previous fragment will be replaced.

Comment: Oh I have learnt a lot. Thank you so much