# how to remove fragment after transition to next fragment

Tags: android, fragment

i use fragment As follows :

```
 img_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.freamlayout,fragment_home);
            ft.remove(fragment_setting);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    img_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment_home);
            ft.replace(R.id.freamlayout,fragment_setting);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

but when transition to fragment 2 , stays fragment 1
how to fix it ??

img1:

[image: img1]

img2:

[image: img2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: fragments overlapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274732/android-fragments-overlapping-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call replace() which does both:

Removes the added fragments, and adds the new one you are passing as the second argument.

See: 
[FragmentTransaction replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#replace_6)

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=ru) for `fragmentTransaction.replace()`

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

Check

- Be sure you are using v4 fragments, because app [fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=ru#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) are depricated in android P.

**Most easy approach**

If nothing works for you, put background on parent node of both of fragment layout. so the old fragment does not appear behind this.